# application:didReceiveLocalNotification never called on ios 8

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, ios8

Is there any known problem issue with:

```
application:didReceiveLocalNotification delegate
```

on iOS 8?

My application creates local notifications using `UILocalNotification`. When application is in background I get notifications, and when I click on the notification banner, it moves to my app. But this method:

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

is never called on iOS 8(Xcode 5.1.1), but works well on iOS 7 or earlier.

P.S. I've also tested project from this site:
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/
 and it doesn't work on iOS 8.

Comment: same issue found with ios8beta5.

Comment: You didn't mention that you build your app in Xcode 5 with SDK 7.1.

Comment: @edzio- `didReceiveLocalNotification` is only called when your app is in the FOREGROUND. So when it's in the background and you click the notification banner, it would not call that method. 
Check out:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html
Do a ctrl-F for:
"Listing 2-6 Handling a local notification when an app is already running"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this for iOS8

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{

}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. But the question is still why method didReceiveLocalNotification doesn't work.

Comment: I think the case is not that it doesn't work, but that in iOS 8, the method called when you tap the banner to open the app changed. See session 713 from WWDC 2014 for more information.

Comment: I believe [StackOverflow's chatrooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) would suffice for such trivialities, @Rajneesh071.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 , Am I the only one that uses iOS 8 and this method never called, but the old one called (didReceiveLocalNotification) ?

Comment: If you will add interactive notification , then this method will called.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the solution on iOS 8 is to request authorization for notifications settings to the user, otherwise the delegate method -didReceiveLocalNotification: will never be called. You can do so by adding this code to the -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                                         settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                                                                         categories:nil]];
}
```

This will show the user an alert view asking for permission to display notifications. If she accepts, the delegate method will be called whenever a local notification is fired.

Answer (score 4):

I meet the same problem...

You must change to use the following code:

```
// register notification for push mechanism        
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                                             settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                                                                             categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

to instead of the original:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the same on iOS8Beta5. Same code works fine on iOS8Beta4.

Edit:
If as the answer suggests, we need to handle it differently - then why did they drop support between two beta builds. It would make sense if iOS8Beta1 build behaved this way. This is why I feel its a bug.

Comment: i am having same issue with ios8beta5.