# Launch app on specific view controller using iOS8 actionable notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have an actionable notification setup on my app with a YES button. Is it possible, when the notification is triggered and you press the Yes button, to take you into the app on a specific view controller, not the initial view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use new method `handleActionWithIdentifier` of iOS8 to this task. Whenever you press action button , these delegate will call.

1. **Delegate for localNotification** : Called when your app has been activated by the user selecting an action from a local notification.

   ```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
   ```
2. **Delegate for remoteNotification** : Called when your app has been activated by the user selecting an action from a remote notification.

   ```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
   ```

**Note : You should call the completion handler as soon as you've finished handling the action.**

Then you can get your `rootViewController` using this and then redirect to other ViewController.

```
- (UIViewController*)GetTopViewController
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        UINavigationController* rvc = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        rootViewController = rvc.visibleViewController;
    }
    return rootViewController;
}
```

Other related [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244281/applicationdidreceivelocalnotification-never-called-on-ios-8/25424051#25424051)

Comment: Thanks for this. I already have these delegates in place. How do I get the app top open on a specific view controller?