# auto run a function in background in ios app when local notification triggers

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to auto run a function once the local notification gets triggered in iOS. `didReceiveLocalNotification` comes in handy in this scenario only when the app is in the foreground. But once the app is in the background, `didReceiveLocalNotification` has no affect. With some research I found out `didReceiveLocalNotification` was meant to run in foreground only.

So, is there any other way to achieve what the scenario demands? My app strictly requires local notification so I can't use push notifications and its `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Comment: There are ways to do this. What do you have sending the local notification? That's probably what's failing to occur.

Comment: @matt.writes.code that was quick :) ... well, the local notification scheduling part is working fine and I am recieving local notifications even when the app is in background ... but its just that the function which I want to run once the app recieves local notification is not getting triggered when the app is in background ..
Well my app scenario is like this : local notification is triggered at scheduled time, the app waits for around 10 mins for user to tap it ... if no action is taken within the 10 mins after notification is triggered , the app needs to record it as MISSED

Comment: @matt.writes.code if its not much of trouble, can you mention the WAYS you are talking about ???

Comment: Try these solutions out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244281/applicationdidreceivelocalnotification-never-called-on-ios-8

Comment: @matt.writes.code thanks.. have not tested but the answer seems to be for interactive local notifications and the sugggested handler seems to be called only when one of the actions in notification is tapped ....  well, I need to auto run the function once the notification gets triggered not tapped

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "alarm clock" style of function where you can execute your app at a specific time in the background. A local notification will be delivered to the user at the scheduled time, but if they don't tap on the notificztion then your app will not run.  The next time your app is launched by the user you can check the date/time against the times when notifications would have been delivered and calculate which notifications were missed